# Bands histogram of TIF image only shows 0

Tags: python, tiff, gdal, qgis

I am working both with QGIS and GDAL lib in python. I've clipped a scence from QGIS and exported it as TIF format.

[TIF image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dgklWHYIJkeo_JBVOLhKkjvI0NQQq_oh/view?usp=share_link)

I've tried something to read the histogram of this image:

```
dataset = gdal.Open("/content/drive/MyDrive/work/6539633101/ClippedDup.tif")
num_bands = dataset.RasterCount
for i in range(1, num_bands+1):
    band = dataset.GetRasterBand(i)
    hist = band.GetHistogram()
    print(f"Histogram of Band {i}: {hist}")
```

I got the histogram like this.

Image

[image: 1]

What should I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect to happen? The data you use doesn't contain any values within the valid range of the histogram you request. You can include those by setting:

```py
hist = band.GetHistogram(include_out_of_range=True)
```

That will put all values in the very last bin, as expected.

You should probably either scale the data, or set the range/bins you want for the histogram, if the current result isn't what you want. See the documentation for all available options:
https://gdal.org/doxygen/classGDALRasterBand.html#aa21dcb3609bff012e8f217ebb7c81953

Alternatively, you can read the data and use something like Numpy (`np.histogram`) to calculate the histogram.

You can test this for example with something like:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,3), facecolor="w")

vmin = 200
vmax = 1400
n_bins = 50
step = int((vmax-vmin)/n_bins)

ds = gdal.Open("/content/drive/MyDrive/work/6539633101/ClippedDup.tif")
num_bands = ds.RasterCount

for i in range(1, num_bands+1):
    
    band = ds.GetRasterBand(i)
    hist = band.GetHistogram(min=vmin, max=vmax, buckets=n_bins, include_out_of_range=True)
    
    ax.step(range(vmin, vmax, step), hist, label=f"Band {i}")

ax.legend()
```

[image]